# How is math.copysign(x, y) in Python useful?

Tags: python, function, math

I was going over the functions of the math module in Python and found the math.copysign (x,y) function. I want to know when someone would use this function.  I check many websites and they show how to use the function. I understand how to use it, but I would like to know in which cases it will be useful to get the absolute value of the first argument and the sign of the second.

```
math.copysign(x, y)
```

Comment: No, Python does have one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one easy example. Suppose I'm writing a game, and I want the enemy to move toward the player at a given speed. The speed is determined by one variable and the direction is determined by where the player is

```
enemy.velocity = math.copysign(enemy.base_speed, player.xposition - enemy.xposition)
```

This sort of vector math (here, it's really just directional math, since we're dealing in one dimension) becomes second nature when you've used it awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful when trying to find positive or negative floats.

I just stumbled on error in my code, which was solved by copysign:

```
#Error:
#a is a float value:
a=-0.0004
if int(a) < 0:
   #do something
```

Won't work, because int(-0.004) will be 0, which has no sign.

So had to change to:

```
a=-0.0004
if math.copysign(1,a) < 0:
   #do something
```

Comment: why did you convert to int "int(a)"? Without the conversion, your first code works: