# Negative percentages in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

-5 is a greater negative than -3. How can I express this change in Python 3 as a continuing negative and STILL KEEP the negative sign? (-5 divided by -3 (rounded) computes as 1.67)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you are computing.  -5 is +1.67 times as negative as -3.  No way the result should be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, a negative number divided by a negative number is a positive number.

However, if you want to preserve the sign, you can use `math.copysign`:

```py
import math

a = -5
b = -3

# Divides `a` and `b` preserving the sign of `a`
print(math.copysign(a / b, a))    # -1.6666666666666667
```

Comment: There's an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893878/how-is-math-copysignx-y-in-python-useful) about copysign - it might be worthwhile generalizing this over there. Doesn't necessarily mean this one has to close.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` and `b` will always be negative, you can multiply one of them with `-1`:

```
a = -5
b = -3

return round(a/(b*-1))
```

If not always negative, you can use `if` to check:

```
if (a && b) < 0:
  return round(a/(b*-1))

return round(a/b)
```